# Result chaining promise with throw JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I can't really understand how the promise will work here:

```js
Promise.resolve(1)
    .then(x => x + 1)
    .then(x => { throw x })
    .then(x => console.log(x))
    .catch(err => console.log(err)) // 2
    .then(x => Promise.resolve(1))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(x => console.log(x)) // 1
```

from MDN: [The Promise returned by catch() is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)
, so why it doesn't stop after catch?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

1. `Promise.resolve(1)` creates a promise fulfilled with the value `1`.
2. `.then(x => x + 1)` adds a fulfillment handler to that promise, creating a new promise (`.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` always create promise). When the fulfillment handler is called, it will take the fulfillment value of the promise it was called on as `x`, add `1` to it, and use that to fulfill its promise.
3. `.then(x => { throw x })` adds a fulfillment handler to the promise from Step 2, creating a new promise. When called, the fulfillment handler will take the fulfillment value of the promise it was attached to (`1 + 1` is `2`) and use that to `throw` a value. This rejects the promise this second `.then` created.
4. `.catch(err => console.log(err))` adds a rejection handler to that promise. When the rejection handler is called, it takes the rejection reasons (which we know will be `2`) as `err` and logs it. Since the rejection handler doesn't throw an error or return a promise that is rejected or will reject, it converts rejection to fulfillment. In this case, it uses the return value of `console.log` to fulfill its promise. That value is `undefined`.

...and then the same sort of pattern is repeated again.

Key bits there are:

- `.then`, `.catch`, and `.finally` create promises
- If you return a value (explicitly or implicitly) from a fulfillment or rejection handler, and that value isn't a promise that is rejected or will reject, it fulfills the promise `.then` or `.catch` created with that value.
- If you throw (or return a promise that is rejected or will reject) in a `.then` or `.catch` handler, you reject the promise `.then` or `.catch` created.

---

If you're not entirely clear on the terminology around promises ("fulfill," "reject," "resolve" [which I didn't use above, but the code did]), I [have a blog post for that](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/). ;-)

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in detail in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: [The Promise returned by catch() is rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is itself rejected; otherwise, it is resolved.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), so why it doesn't stop after catch?

Comment: @Aygul - See #4 above. The `catch` handler doesn't throw an error or return a promise that is rejected (or will reject), so it converts rejection into fulfillment (like a `catch` on a `try`/`catch` does if you don't `throw` from it).

Comment: @Aygul You wrote it yourself: "*otherwise, it is resolved*". Why would you expect it to "stop"? Do you mean it should never settle to anything?